# How to reliably connect to pixelbook linux ports on localhost?

Tags: linux, google-chrome-os

I've been running development web services on my pixelbook's linux VM like this.

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 router.php
```

Normally, I can then connect to these development services in Chrome with:

```
http://localhost:8000/whatever
```

However, this occasionally fails, forcing me to look up the linux VM's IP address:

```
$ hostname -I
100.115.92.199
```

And then connecting (successfully) with that IP:

```
http://100.115.92.199:8000/whatever
```

When the `localhost` fails, it tends to get "stuck" in failure. It will occasionally resolve "on it's own". But, I have no idea how to actually fix it.

**How can I consistently make Chrome OS see the linux environment as `localhost`?**

*(Or some other **predictable** hostname that I don't have to look up.)*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where this is *officially* documented, but I've recently found that the `penguin.linux.test` hostname is mapped to the default linux container. This was worked reliably for me for some time when `localhost` has not.

As I understand it, `penguin` is the container name, so new containers would be `{containername}.linux.test`.